# How to access new page in wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am having a `wordpress` issue in my site.

I am trying to modify someone's works and I want to add a new page with customized html codes.

I really don't like wordpress's admin panel so I want to use my own text editor to edit the file.

I created a `test.php` file under the `wp-content/theme/` and it seems I can't access that file from the url `(ex: www.mysite.com/test`) while he has so many files under that folder (like `about.php and home.ph`p). I have never tried `wordpress` and I usually codes my site manually. Can someone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Wordpress is database driven. There are no files for each page.

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Custom_Page_Templates

Comment: Put your `test.php` inside the active theme folder(`wp-content/theme/<active-theme-name>`) and not inside `wp-content/theme`, and load `www.mysite.com/test.php`

Comment: do you want test.php to run as a template page or stand alone?

Comment: I want test.php to run as a tempalte page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you've already created test.php under `/wp-content/themes/theme_name/`.

Go into the `/wp-admin/` control panel. Log in, and go to 'Pages'. There, select the page you want to add (or create one first). Then, when the editor is open, see the right side for what template to use. Select test and go from there.

Comment: Thanks so if I create a test.php under theme folder the new theme will appear on the right side of the template drowdown menu? +1

Comment: Not a theme - a mere template file. Try it out, there's not a lot that can go wrong ;).

Comment: add <?php
/*
Template Name: My Custom Test Page
*/ ?> as the first part of test.php and it shows up where Mave said.